# Converting an integer to a ASCII key String

Tags: java

How does one go about converting an integer like

int keycode = 65;

into

String keycode = "a"?

Thanks everyone, I know how to do it vice-versa, I've searched all over and have not found a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will do:

```
String str = String.valueOf((char)keycode);
```

Comment: Vouch. Easiest way to get an int value into a ASCII key letter.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to do your operation. Since You have `0 to 255` `ASCII` values, You need to validate it before manipulating.

```
    int value = 65;
    if (value >= 0 && value <= 255) {
        char character = (char) value;
    }
```

Comment: Strictly speaking ASCII is 0-127.

Comment: @Dunes I incluedes Extended ASCII Codes too.

Comment: Extended ASCII is not ASCII. There are an hoards of character encodings that that are identical to to ASCII below 128, but have radically different characters for 128-255. Compare ISO/IEC 8859-1 (Latin-1/extended ASCII) and ISO/IEC 8859-8 (Latin/Hebrew). We don't which country OP is from, so you shouldn't make assumptions about which character set might be in use.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Character.toString((char) keycode);
```

Comment: That's going to give a result of "65"

Comment: sry that is my mistake....edited